# ¿Cómo corregir estos errores en login con formik?

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, api, formularios, cors

Estoy haciendo un form de registro y login con formik, tengo todas las rutas implementadas y me salen dos errores: (en postman todo bien)

**El primer error con la ruta, este es el error que me sale en la consola**

> POST http://localhost:3000/undefined/auth/register 404 (Not Found)

**Acá las configuraciones**

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();

//Using dotenv
require("dotenv").config();

//Mongoose config
require("./server/config/mongoose.config");

//Using cors
app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: "http://localhost:3000" }));

//Access POST method
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

//Calling all routes
require("./server/routes/user.routes")(app);

//Using the port
app.listen(process.env.PORT, () =>
  console.log(`CORS-enabled web server listening on port ${process.env.PORT}`)
);
```

Me meto en la consola, en la parte de ***red*** y me sale esto

```
Cannot POST /undefined/auth/register
```

Acá está la ruta

```
const { registerUser } = require("../controllers/user.controller");

module.exports = (app) => {
  app.post("/api/auth/register", registerUser);
```

**Y  otro error es con el form de formik, es decir al darle registrarme en el formulario sale esto tambien**

```
Warning: An unhandled error was caught from submitForm() TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'message')
    at registerUser
```

HELP!!!

Para que se hagan una idea, adjunto foto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El error está en la petición, no nos sirve de nada ver el código de tu servidor si no nos muestras cómo haces la petición desde tu UI, porque en lugar de llamar a `/api/...` está llamando a `/undefined/...`.

Comment: @KroneauxSchneider aqui esta la petición 
```
//Registrar el usuario
    const registerUser = async (values, {resetForm}) =>{
        try{
            const response = await axiosWithoutToken("auth/register", values, "POST");
            console.log(response);
```
El axiosWithoutTOken lo tengo en una carpeta helpers

```
import axios from "axios";


export const axiosWithoutToken = (endpoint, data, method = "GET") => {
  const url = `${baseUrl}/${endpoint}`;
  return axios({ method, url, data });
};

obviamente esta importada en donde hago la llamada en compnent registerUser

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta para añadir los detalles. No olvides añadir de dónde obtienes tu `baseUrl`.

Comment: Ya lo resolví. Tenía el archivo .env en la carpeta src  y debía estar afuera.